How to navigate from a react app running on port 5173 to another react app running on port 5174 during development?
I am building a project in which there is a backend server and two react apps (frontend which is a website and dashboard) both running on different ports. Once the user logs in, in the frontend he is able to see a dashboard option. On clicking on dashboard he is able to go to his dashboard. How to navigate the user from frontend to dashboard if both the frontend and dashboard are two separate react apps running on ports 5173 and 5174 respectively.
I hardcoded the dashboard's url for now, http://localhost:5174/dashboard" in the anchor tag

You can use links <a href=http://localhost:5174/dashboard">Dashboard</a> and <a href=http://localhost:5173/">Website</a>

If your frontend and dashboard are two separate React apps running on different ports, navigating between them can be straightforward. Since they’re essentially two different web apps, you’ll need to redirect the user from one app to the other by sending them to the dashboard’s URL.
Here’s how you can handle it:
Redirecting to the Dashboard
In your frontend React app, when the user clicks on the "Dashboard" option, you can redirect them to the dashboard's URL. You don’t need to hardcode the URL if you define it dynamically in your app's configuration.
For example:
// Inside your frontend React component
const goToDashboard = () => {
  window.location.href = "http://localhost:5174"; // Replace with your dashboard's URL
};

// In your component's JSX
<button onClick={goToDashboard}>Go to Dashboard</button>

When the user clicks the button, they’ll be redirected to the dashboard app running on port 5174.
